# Cisco 871, NAT, port formwarding and VOIP configuration - phone speaker buzz

Tags: cisco, nat, voip

I'm new to all Cisco stuff and I need to configure nettalk VOIP. I have Cisco 871 device with two ISP - one via PPP (public IP 666.666.666.666) and one via eth (public IP 999.999.999.999).

Main ISP is the one via PPP, eth ISP is used for WWW/mail/VOIP.

Nettalk device uses following ports:

Port 69: Used for updates (not necessary for phone calls).
Port 5060: Standard SIP port for provisioning to the netTALK network.
Port 10,000 - 20,000: Used for Voice transmission. If your router does not allow you to put in a range of ports then select port 12000.
Protocol: UDP. TCP is NOT used.

For VOIP I only need 5060 and 10000-20000 (or 12000 if it is not possible to forward port range).

Device IP is 192.168.1.6

I've created permit rules inside "webmailvoip" access-list:

```
permit tcp host 192.168.1.6 any eq 5060
permit udp host 192.168.1.6 any eq 5060
permit udp host 192.168.1.6 any range 10000 20000
permit tcp any eq 5060 host 192.168.1.6
permit udp any eq 5060 host 192.168.1.6
permit udp any range 10000 20000 host 192.168.1.6
```

But it seems that this is not working - I can only hear buzz.

Any ideas which rules are wrong, what else should I configure?

Thank you, best regards!

PS. My current config:

```
version 12.4
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname gw
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
logging buffered 128000
logging console warnings
!
no aaa new-model
!
!
dot11 syslog
ip cef
!
no ip domain lookup
ip domain name blablabla
ip auth-proxy max-nodata-conns 3
ip admission max-nodata-conns 3
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
vpdn enable
!
vpdn-group 1
 request-dialin
  protocol pppoe
!
!
!
username admin privilege 15 password 0 blablabla
!
!
archive
 log config
  logging enable
  hidekeys
!
!
ip ssh version 2
!
track 1 rtr 1
!
track 2 rtr 2
!
!
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.252
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 no ip route-cache cef
 no ip route-cache
 ip policy route-map loop
!
interface Loopback1
 ip address 1.1.1.5 255.255.255.252
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 no ip route-cache cef
 no ip route-cache
 ip policy route-map loop1
!
interface FastEthernet0
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface FastEthernet1
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface FastEthernet2
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface FastEthernet3
 switchport access vlan 3
!
interface FastEthernet4
 mac-address b055.5555.0775
 ip address dhcp
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
!
interface Vlan2
 ip address 192.168.1.252 255.255.255.0 secondary
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
 no ip redirects
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 no ip route-cache cef
 no ip route-cache
 ip policy route-map webmailvoip
!
interface Vlan3
 no ip address
 ip virtual-reassembly
 pppoe enable group global
 pppoe-client dial-pool-number 1
!
interface Dialer0
 ip address negotiated
 ip mtu 1492
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 encapsulation ppp
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1450
 dialer pool 1
 dialer-group 1
 ppp authentication chap callin
 ppp chap hostname blablabla
 ppp chap password 0 blablabla
 ppp ipcp dns request
 ppp ipcp address accept
!
ip forward-protocol nd
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Dialer0 track 1
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 999.999.999.001 100 track 2
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip nat pool POOL 1.1.1.2 1.1.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.1.5 80 interface Dialer0 80
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.1.7 10000 interface Dialer0 10000
ip nat inside source static udp 192.168.1.7 10000 interface Dialer0 10000
ip nat inside source static esp 192.168.1.7 interface Dialer0
ip nat inside source route-map rmap-dial interface Dialer0 overload
ip nat inside source route-map rmap-f4 interface FastEthernet4 overload
ip nat outside source list publicip pool POOL
!
ip access-list extended inside
 permit ip 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 any
ip access-list extended publicip
 permit ip 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 host 999.999.999.999
 permit ip 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 host 666.666.666.666
 permit ip host 666.666.666.666 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
 permit ip host 999.999.999.999 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
ip access-list extended webmailvoip
 deny   ip host 192.168.1.25 any
 permit tcp 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 any eq www
 permit tcp 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 any eq 443
 permit tcp 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 any eq 143
 permit tcp 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 any eq 993
 permit tcp 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 any eq 587
 permit tcp 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 any eq 465
 permit tcp 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 any eq pop3
 permit tcp 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 any eq 995
 permit tcp 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 any eq 22
 permit tcp host 192.168.1.6 any eq 5060
 permit udp host 192.168.1.6 any eq 5060
 permit udp host 192.168.1.6 any range 10000 20000
 permit tcp any eq 5060 host 192.168.1.6
 permit udp any eq 5060 host 192.168.1.6
 permit udp any range 10000 20000 host 192.168.1.6
!
ip sla 1
 icmp-echo 666.666.666.001 source-interface Dialer0
 timeout 3000
 frequency 3
ip sla schedule 1 life forever start-time now
ip sla 2
 icmp-echo 999.999.999.001 source-interface FastEthernet4
 timeout 3000
 frequency 3
ip sla schedule 2 life forever start-time now
access-list 115 permit ip host 192.168.1.35 any log
access-list 115 permit ip any host 192.168.1.35 log
access-list 115 permit ip any any
access-list 117 permit ip 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 host 999.999.999.999
access-list 117 permit ip 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 host 666.666.666.666
access-list 117 permit ip host 666.666.666.666 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 log
access-list 117 permit ip host 999.999.999.999 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 log
dialer-list 1 protocol ip permit
no cdp run
!
route-map webmailvoip permit 10
 match ip address webmailvoip
 set ip next-hop verify-availability 999.999.999.001 1 track 2
 set ip next-hop verify-availability
!
route-map loop permit 10
 set ip next-hop 1.1.1.6
!
route-map loop1 permit 10
 set interface Vlan2
!
route-map rmap-dial permit 10
 match interface Dialer0
!
route-map rmap-f4 permit 10
 match interface FastEthernet4
!
control-plane
!
line con 0
 no modem enable
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 exec-timeout 30 0
 privilege level 15
 login local
 transport input telnet ssh
!
scheduler max-task-time 5000
!
end
```